# Can 当作 ever be used with a direct object behind it?

Tags: meaning

If you look up 当作 it says something like 'treat as, regard as, look upon', however, from what I can see, it only gets used in combination with 把 or 被。
Is this 把 a word with meaning, or a particle?

Is it at all possible, lets say, to rewrite

别把我当作外人。 with the form '当作我‘ and not use '把’？ Maybe '别当做我为外人。‘

Don't treat me as an outsider.

Comment: 别当我作外人. Informal but grammatical.

Comment: Aha, a bit like using 给 to indicate Dative. But you cannot put '把我‘ after '当作‘ can you?  Not like '他给我打电话。‘ or '他打电话给我。‘ Does '把‘ have a meaning in my sentence?

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot do that.

Please always use 把 or 被.

把: take

被: be taken as

别把我当作外人: 
Don't take me as an outsider

我被当做了外人: 
I'm taken as an outsider

Answer (score 1):

in the context 把 serves the same purpose as 将, which are both prep.

把 is usually used together with 当作, 把A当作B means treat A as B.
Such as:
"do not treat me as an out-sider" - 别把我当作外人.

However you can actually use 当 without 把, such as:
别当我傻-do not think I am stupid.
别当我不知道你做了什么-do not think I do not know what you have done.
Though this usage of 当 is more colloquial.

Answer (score 1):

To make this simple..

```
别把我当作外人

別当我为外人
```

Normally we don't say "`別当作我为外人`", just because we need an opposite B  after `当作`, so it could be like "`treat 我(A) as 外人(B)`".

When we see “`把`”，it's more like an emphasis on Whom, "`Don't treat *Me* as outsider`"

Comment: If it is just emphasis, could I leave it out? '别我当作外人‘ Doesn't sound too good!

Comment: The order of 我 and 当 is important here. Don't put me (in a position to be) treated as outsider. vs Don't treat me as outsider.

Comment: @Pedroski from the grammar, we will have to use 把 before 我, because 别 is same as Don't, it can't be "Don't me...", even though 把 is extra here for 当作，it just a modifier when we put 我 ahead of 当作

Answer (score 0):

My answer is not directly relevant to this question. But it would be good practice for you to learn "把字句" and "被字句". In China, these are offered as fundamental Chinese courses in primary school.